# Может ли произойти ошибка при одновременном считывании и записи объекта в файл?

Tags: java, файлы, сериализация, запись, десериализация

К примеру, есть класс, в котором два метода, один ЗАПИСЫВАЕТ объект в файл, а другой СЧИТЫВАЕТ, может ли произойти ошибка, при одновременной ЗАПИСИ и СЧИТЫВАНИЯ файла, я знаю, что при ЗАПИСИ, создаётся новый файл, а старый затирается, или как? А другой метод будет СЧИТЫВАТЬ со старого файла, или уже с нового. А что, если новый файл при записи не успеет создаться полностью, а другой метод начнёт СЧИТЫВАТЬ не до конца созданный файл? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

```
class Saver {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public synchronized <P, V> Optional<Map<P, V>> deserializationOf(String mapName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {               
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mapName); 
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);       
        Map<P, V> map = (Map<P, V>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        return Optional.of(map);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    public synchronized <P, V> void serializationOf(String mapName, Map<P, V> map) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mapName);    
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(map);
        objectOutputStream.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Считывание и запись в файл  - синхронизированные операции. Тоесть, если вы читаете из файла, то другой поток/процесс не сможет записывать в него.

Comment: Вот эти методы сверху нужно синхронизировать, или в данном случай можно не бояться?